# Calculate double complex integral $\iint_{r<|z|<R} f(z) dxdy$ in unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}=\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|<R\} $ and continous at $\mathbb{D} \cup \partial \mathbb{D}$. Calculate
>   $$\displaystyle \iint_{r<|z|<R} f(z) dxdy$$

my try: Since $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$ then $f$ has primitive in it $F=u+iv$ and $F'=u_x-iu_y=f$ so from Green theorem we have $\displaystyle \iint_{r<|z|<R} f(z) dxdy =  \iint_{r<|z|<R} u_x-iu_y dxdy = \int_{\gamma}iudx+udy$ where $\gamma$ is parametrization of $r<|z|<R$

is my reasoing correct ? and how can this be simplified ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After subtracting the constant $f(0)$ from $f$ we may assume $f(0)=0$. Then $g(z):={f(z)\over z}$ is analytic in $D_R$. It follows that
$$J_0:=\int_{a\leq|z|\leq b}f(z)\>{\rm d}(x,y)=\int_a^b r\int_0^{2\pi}f(re^{i\phi})\>d\phi\>dr\ .$$
Now
$$\int_0^{2\pi}f(re^{i\phi})\>d\phi={1\over i}\int_0^{2\pi}{f(re^{i\phi})\over r e^{i\phi}}i r e^{i\phi}\>d\phi={1\over i}\int_{\partial D_r}g(z)\>dz=0\qquad(0\leq r\leq R)\ ,$$
by Cauchy's theorem. It follows that $J_0=0$. From this we conclude that for the original $f$ one has 
$$\int_{a\leq|z|\leq b}f(z)\>{\rm d}(x,y)=\pi(b^2-a^2)f(0)\ .$$
This is the mean value property of harmonic functions.

Comment: Could you elaborate why from $J_0=0$ we know that : $\pi(b^2-a^2)f(0)\ $? And also $g(z)$ has primitive on $D_R$? I mean we divide by $z$, and zero is in $D_R$.

Comment: @vanHohenheim: See my edit. Note that when $f(0)=0$ we are allowed to divide by $z$ and obtain an analytic function.

Answer (score 0):

A parameterization of a region (as opposed to a curve) is possible but unpleasant.

Try expressing the double integral in polar coordinates. Instead of writing $z = x + iy$ you can write $z = \rho e^{i \theta}$ and apply Fubini's theorem. Integrate $f$ on concentric circles with radius $\rho$ in between $r$ and $R$.